# Change CenterOffset of an AnnotationView after zooming

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MKMapView ignores update of centerOffset in iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136505/mkmapview-ignores-update-of-centeroffset-in-ios-4)

I need to change the centerOffset property of an AnnotationView when the zoomlevel changed.

Any ideas about this?

Best Regards
Lima

Comment: HowsItStack appears to ask the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136505/mkmapview-ignores-update-of-centeroffset-in-ios-4) with not much resolution.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me in ios5 - to be specific, I have a custom annotation view which changes its frame (expands and collapses).  I need to adjust the centerOffset after the frame change otherwise the annotation view would be in the wrong place after the zoom level of the map changes.